# Clarify costs on my credit card printout when buying apps. 

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I have a iPad 2. In my credit card printout, I have a cost from an app I bought in the AppStore. But I've only installed free apps.

If I lookup what apps I've installed, I cannot see their costs, because I can only see "Installed" information. How can I see the App price when I install it?

Or there is a way to check what I bought and what is charged me?

Comment: Michiel's answer is correct; also Apple sends receipts via email, so you can search for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you open iTunes and navigate to *Store < Show account*, there is a history of what you bought including the date and price for every transaction.

I'm sorry for the Dutch language in the screenshot:
[image]